# Activate CI/CD pipelines for every repo on my GitLab-Server

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want every Repository on my GitLab-Server to have one specific CI/CD pipeline. Is something like this supported in git/GitLab?

Based on my research, the only way to achieve something similar would be to implement a [post-receive server hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive), but as far as I see, I would have to manually implement some kind of notification system for the user and I would lose the nice user interface built for CI/CD pipelines, which would be ugly and sad.

(Also, I don't want to use something like pre-receive server hooks or any other hooks that prevent the user from committing or pushing, since my pipeline has the potential to take quite a few minutes and I don't want the User to wait ten minutes on the command line just to watch a simple repo getting pushed.)

So, is there any way to implement CI/CD pipelines as a requirement and as automatically activated for every repository on the server?

One more clarification: I don't want a net of pipelines across several repositories. I have one standalone pipeline that should be run on every (existing and future) repository as its own pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

Yes we can use downstream pipeline as common pipeline for every project in a Gitlab server.

GitLab EE supports it, I hope below documentation can help you.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html

Comment: Am I missing something or is that just a way to link several repositories and their respective pipelines?